# Custom routes management

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to use custom routes handling code?
For example client requests server on `http://server.com/api/v1/json/profile/` and my code calls `ApiController`, `MyAction` action with parameters `version=1`, `format=json`, `action=profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  You'll have to use a different parameter name for action so you don't have a conflict with the controller action.

```
.MapRoute("name", "api/v{version}/{format}/{_action}", new { controller = "ApiController", action = "MyAction" });
```

**EDIT** made version work the way you wanted.

Comment: Yes :) Sorry - that's what you get for doing it off the top of your head.

Answer (score 1):

I would start off by renaming the "action" parameter to something else otherwise the route is going to get very confusing (maybe call it purpose?). Also, I believe something like the following would work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    // name of your route
    "MyRoute",

    // route template
    "api/v{version}/{format}/{purpose}",

    // default route values
    new {
        controller = "ApiController",
        action = "MyAction",
    },

    // constraints placed on parameters (make sure they are valid) 
    new {
        version = @"^\d+$",            // number only (can also include decimals)
        format = @"^(json|text|xml)$", // if you want filtering...
    }
);
```

Then:

```
public ApiController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult MyAction(Int32 version, String format, String purpose)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```